# jQuery: How to post data after clicking on a link without ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I've got the following links in my page:

```
<a href='/post/view/12' id='93' class='notification_link'>your post</a>
<a href='/post/view/13' id='112' class='notification_link'>your post</a>
```

Whenever the user clicks on any of the above links, I need to post the id of the link (e.g. 93) along with the post id (e.g 12) to the (/post/view) page. But I don't want to do this via ajax. I want to be redirected to the /post/view page as if the user has clicked on the link. So far I've come up with the following code, but don't know how to continue. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", '.notification_link', setNotification);
});

function setNotification(e){
    targetUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post(targetUrl, { id: $(this).attr('id'), view_id: "12" }, null);
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Forms are designed to make POST requests. Use a form.

Comment: FYI - `$.post` that you are using is an AJAX call. You said you don't want to use it, do you?

Comment: @dotnetom No I don't want to use ajax.

Comment: If you really don't want to use ajax why don't you do the routing in PHP with GET variables? `href='/post?view=12&id=93'` If instead you want to keep the URL pretty, use a form.

Comment: @colonelsanders I don't want the `id=93` to be visible in the url.

Comment: so you want to pass both the a tag id and the post id to another page without using ajax and without using a query string? the post view page will use this data in some way right?

Comment: can redirect at server once you have the url query string params so they don't show in final url in browser

Comment: @zero that's what I need to do.

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding something then if the post page needs the data then you could create a cookie or store it in local storage and redirect then retrieve the data when you need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this without ajax then you can try this...

```
function setNotification(e){
    targetUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('<form/>').append('<input name="id" value="'+ id +'"/><input name="view_id" value="12"/>').attr('action', targetUrl ).attr('method', 'POST').appendTo('body').submit();

    return false; 
};
```

Comment: It needed an `.appendTo('body')` before `submit()` to work i Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar scenario I used cookies to save the value I didn't want to appear in the URL. Put the handler in the mousedown event so that the cookie will be created before the new page starts to load.

```
jQuery('a.notification_link').mousedown(function () {
    var myid = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    //here save in a cookie, you can use your own code to save in a cookie
    create_cookie('notification_link', myid, 0);
});
```

And you can get this value both in the code behind and also in the client side.